# Which is better in the following scenario? useEffect or useMemo?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have the following custom hook that basically fetches data from a smart contract:

```
export const usePoolLength = () => {
    const [length, setLength] = useState(0);

    const _getPoolLength = useCallback(async () => {
        const poolLength = await getPoolLength();
        setLength(poolLength);
    }, [])

    useMemo(() => {
        _getPoolLength();
    }, [_getPoolLength]);

    return { length }
}

export const getPoolLength = async () => {
   const poolLength = await masterchefV2Contract.poolLength();
   return poolLength.toNumber();
}
```

I understand that calling an API is a side effect but should I be using `useEffect` or `useMemo`? It seems like there is no difference so I'm not thinking about changing to `useEffect`. Wanted to get some opinions/advise, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is clearly mentioned in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo):

> Remember that the function passed to useMemo runs during rendering. Don’t do anything there that you wouldn’t normally do while rendering. For example, side effects belong in useEffect, not useMemo.

Also consider the fact that `_getPoolLength` is not being used anywhere else. It is a method that is only useful for the API call so why not define it inside the effect and use it there only.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your custom hook doesn't need to refetch the data.

```
export const usePoolLength = () => {
    const [length, setLength] = useState(0);
    // Your refrence is same throught the lifecycle
    const _getPoolLength = useCallback(async () => {
        const poolLength = await getPoolLength();
        setLength(poolLength);
        return poolLength;
    }, [])
   // Cached value and value available during  render itself.
   const poolLength = useMemo(()=> _getPoolLength(), [_getPoolLength]);

    return { length }
}

export const getPoolLength = async () => {
   const poolLength = await masterchefV2Contract.poolLength();
   return poolLength.toNumber();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `useCallback` / `useMemo` combination here seems a little tangled. `useEffect` is more straightforward, perhaps easier to read:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    getPoolLength().then(setLength);
    // or getPoolLength().then(fetchedLength => setLength(fetchedLength));
}, []);
```

Comment: Good explaination, but it won't work because the outer function. The hook expects a `length` value which might not be ready soon due the awaited call.

Comment: @MarioVernari `getPoolLength()` returns a Promise, which the `.then(..)` chains off. `setLength(..)` isn't called until the awaited value is ready.

Comment: exactly what I'm saying. The outer `usePoolLength` isn't aync and exits immediately. However, the `useEffect` content may be delayed due the promise. All that likely leads a `length` equals zero and soon after the useful value, but without ability to read from outside.

Comment: The (outer) `usePoolLength` hook does indeed always return immediately, even in your original formulation. When `setLength` is called with the updated value `length` is updated, causing a re-render of the component that calls the hook.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you actually use `useCallback` with `useMemo` in combination with `useState` ?

I think you should just use the `useMemo` hook like this:

```js
const length = useMemo(async () => {
    await _getPoolLength()
}, [_getPoolLength]);
```